# Testing results with Massive

Tags: massive

I'm returning a list to my MVC controller from Massive. When I'm in my test how can I check that there are 3 records (as expected) in the returned list?

My test code currently returns the 3 records from a call and populates into my ViewModel (model) but when I try to run `.Count()` it's saying object has no `Count` method. Since it's a `dynamic` type what do I do?

My test code:

```
var result = _controller.Index() as ViewResult;
var model = result.Model as MyExperienceListModel;
Assert.AreEqual(3, model.Experience.Count());
```

model.Experience is `dynamic` btw.

Comment: Could you post some more code up please of your problem.. Are you sure you've got System.Linq referenced?

Comment: Yes I have System.Linq referenced

Comment: I came across a similar issue -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733305/count-on-an-ienumerabledynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by having my returned result set from my Massive class as a `IEnumerable<dynamic>` in my `ViewModel`. So:

```
MyExperienceListModel{
 public IEnumerable<dynamic> Experience { get; set;}
}
```

Hope it helps someone else out.