# Count on an IEnumerable<dynamic>

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic, massive

I'm using Rob Conery's Massive ORM.

Is there an elegant way to do a count on the record set returned?

```
dynamic viewModelExpando = result.ViewData.Model;
var queryFromMassiveDynamic = viewModelExpando.TenTricksNewestFirst;

//fails as have actually got TryInvokeMember on it
var z = queryFromMassiveDynamic.Count();

//works
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in queryFromMassiveDynamic) {
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than calling it using the extension method member syntax, try calling the static method directly.

```
int count = Enumerable.Count(queryFromMassiveDynamic);
```

Comment: +1 of course... the extension method wouldn't be found. I'm intrigued by the runtime overload resolution magic of dynamic. I seem to always forget about that.

Answer (score 5):

You can take sehe's answer, which is to cast the result.

```
var z = (queryFromMassiveDynamic as IEnumerable<dynamic>).Count();
```

Instead, realize what you are getting from the Query member function.  You are in fact getting an IEnumerable of type dynamic and var has trouble with those.

Change this line

```
var queryFromMassiveDynamic = viewModelExpando.TenTricksNewestFirst;
```

To this

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> queryFromMassiveDynamic = viewModelExpando.TenTricksNewestFirst;
```

Count will show up without having to do any casting.

Answer (score 4):

The question is a bit off. You're not actually doing a count of an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. You're *trying* a count on a `dynamic` (which hopefully *holds* an `IEnumerable`).

The straightforward way to do this is by using a cast:

```
 var z = (queryFromMassiveDynamic as IEnumerable<dynamic>).Count();
```